# Looping through directories to extract pages from multiple pdfs

Tags: batch-file, pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I have multiple directories that contain one pdf in each. Im trying to extract page 1 from each pdf and keep it in the directory that the original pdf was in so i end up with the multiple directories now containing two pdfs.

I currently have this code using ghost scripts which works, but only if the pdfs are in the same directory as the batch file

```
echo on
for %%I in ("D:\files\input\" *.pdf) do "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.20\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="%%~nI_p1.pdf" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 "%%I"
```

I cant see why all the directories in D:\files\input\ are not being looped through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of the for loop is the problem. See `for /?`
Magoo was faster, see this complete solution.

```
@Echo off
Set "GS=C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.20\bin\gswin64c.exe"
Set "Opt=-dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1"
Pushd "D:\files\input\"
for /f "delims=" %%I in (
  'Dir /B/S *.pdf ^|find /v "_p1.pdf" '
) do If not exist "%%~dpnI_p1.pdf" "%GS%" %Opt% -sOutputFile="%%~dpnI_p1.pdf" "%%~fI"
Popd
```

Comment: This worked perfectly first time, thank you very much!

Comment: Using Magoos hint, yes. Added it above.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing the command with two parameters,`"D:\files\input\"` and  `*.pdf`.

You need to look for each `*.pdf` file. The accepted way is

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /s /a-d "D:\files\input\*.pdf" ') do ...
```

directory, basic format, with subdirectories, but no directorynames.

However, this would execute the command against every `*.pdf` including the `*_p1.pdf`s (ie those already processed) so

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /s /a-d "D:\files\input\*.pdf"^|findstr /v /i /e /L "_p1.pdf" ') do ...
```

would exclude those files by find those names that do not (/v) end (/e) with the literal (/L) "_p1.pdf" without regard to case (/i). It would however regenerate the `_p1`s.

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /s /a-d "D:\files\input\*.pdf" ') do if not exist "%%~dp*_p1.pdf" ...
```

would process those `*.pdf`s that have not already been processed.

(not tested)

Comment: I'd suggest that the `gswin64c.exe` command may also require adjustment - `~dpn` should provide the full pathname + basename.